# Does deleting an IBM COS instance also delete all buckets and files within it?

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I'm aware the COS API has an operation to DELETE an "empty bucket" but what happens when I DELETE a COS instance X with buckets A, B and C inside X and then A, B and C all have multiple files within these buckets?

1) Does deleting the COS instance delete recursively?
2) Does my bucket names become available after a while to use again?
3) Should I be able to verify in UI with usage page that deleted files are no longer counted in my usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per developers in IBM team dealing with Cloud Object Storage:

> When an account is marked for deletion, the buckets that are part of the account are marked for deletion after 7 days. Charges for that account stop immediately after request from user is received, however, actual deletion process is not guaranteed to occur exactly at 7 days, it could take longer. When the buckets are eventually deleted, the bucket names can be reused.

So, as per my questions above, the answers are the following:

1) Yes
2) Yes, best case scenario in 7 days
3) Yes, but might take few minutes